# Applescript: Unable to set miniaturized property of the window when application is a variable

Tags: applescript

I am get the following error when I try to set miniaturized of a window to false/true for an application whose name I supply as a variable.

set x to `"Safari"`

tell application x to set miniaturized of the front window to false

ERROR

> miniaturized-safari.scpt:40:85: execution error: Safari got an error:
>   Can’t make |miniaturized| of window 1 into type specifier. (-1700)

while I don't get any error when I try the following

tell application `"Safari"` to set miniaturized of the front window to false

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript terminology is evaluated at **compile time**.

This is the reason why applications specified in `tell` blocks must be constants.

Comment: But I am able to tell the application perform other actions like opening a location. Something like the below works fine.
set x to "Safari"
tell application x to open location "http://google.com"

Comment: `open location` is (also) part of Standard Additions. It does not necessarily require an application tell block

Comment: I have a followup question, the above works even when run from the applescript editor.
So how is running the script from the shell different from running it from the applescript editor

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with running scripts from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution that is working for me:

```
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    reopen -- unminimizes the first minimized window or makes a new default window
end tell
```

Works for Finder as well. Anyway there are apps it is not working for (eg. Office).

Comment: Hi David, but reopen would only help me in case I want to maximize, what about minimizing the application.